# docker-compose ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because: Service database has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be…

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, docker-compose

To solve upgrade symfony issue, I create a new symfony project.
When create new symfony project (5.4.9), there is the question :

```
The recipe for this package contains some Docker configuration.
    This may create/update docker-compose.yml or update Dockerfile (if it exists).
    Do you want to include Docker configuration from recipes?
```

and I answered *yes* and it create a *docker-compose.yml* and *docker-compose.override.yml*

Then I forgot this and copy my *docker-compose.yml* file in project.

When I want to *up* my containers, it returns :

```
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because: Service database has neither an image nor a build   
context specified. At least one must be provided
```

under Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) with docker-compose v1.29.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by running docker-compose in verbose mode : 
`docker-compose --verbose up -d db` where *db* is my first container (my database project, not the *database* define in symfony docker-compose), I could show it mentioned *docker-compose.override.yml* file that I rename for test.

It solves the error and my containers run now.

see also : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/docker.html